# Load trained YoloV5 model using torch

Tags: python, pytorch, importerror, yolov5

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ngngnhth/anpr-with-yolo-easyocr) to build ANPR with YoloV5 and EasyOCR. After I trained my model I wanted to load it using torch, using this code snippet:

```
import torch

yolo = torch.hub.load(
    'ultralytics/yolov5',
    'custom',
    path='/content/yolov5/runs/train/yolov5s_results/weights/best.pt',
    force_reload=True)
```

but I face this error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'is_jupyter' from 'utils.general' (/content/yolov5/utils/general.py)`

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: bug in yolov5? report to maintainers?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm weird, `is_jupyter` should exist according to [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/utils/general.py). You could try `git pull` again maybe, or delete the repo and completely re-clone the whole thing from scratch? I've experienced some git shenanigans in the automatic1111 stable diffusion webgui, it would update some things and keep other things the same whenever I pulled. Deleting the repo then re-cloning solved it for me as far as missing stuff. Maybe just copy the contents of general.py on the repo? If that doesn't do the trick, I'd do as @ChristophRackwitz recommends and [report the issue](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues).

Also if this is useful info, [they changed the function from `is_notebook` to `is_jupyter` in February](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/commit/3c0a6e664bc3847ab9cca3df66195de6acfeb012), not too long ago. If you've had yolov5 for more than that amount of time, I really think deleting your repo then starting from scratch will almost definitely fix it. Check out your `general.py`, I think it will still have the `is_notebook` function.